# Using PageContentFilter and BinaryContentFilter in 8.5

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, web8.5, experience-manager, java

We have implemented `PageContentFilter` and `BinaryContentFilter`in Tridion 2013 SP1  because we serve pages from custom filesystem location with following code:

```
public class BinaryContentFilterWrapper extends BinaryContentFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (RestDCPAppConfig.isXpmEnabled()) {
            super.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse); 
        }
    }

}
```

Now we need to re-implement this for 8.5, but when I take a look at these classes, they are completely different with new methods, plus `doFilter()` method cannot be implemented since its final.

```
@Override
protected BinaryData fetchBinaryData(String arg0) {}    

@Override
protected String handleBinaryData(PreviewSession arg0, BinaryData arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {}

@Override
protected void doInit() throws SessionHandlingException  {}

@Override
protected PreviewSession obtainPreviewSession()  {}
```

Is there any documentation on how to implement this? Or what these methods are? How should we re-implement `doFilter()` method for XPM?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this Marko?

Comment: No. We contacted support and tey have no clue

Comment: Thanks all the same for your reply. I’m working on the exact same thing so I’ll keep you posted if I make any progress.

Comment: I managed to conditionally execute the XPM filters per environment as outlined in this blog. https://www.contentbloom.com/blog/conditional-sdl-experience-manager-xpm-filters-per-environment/. I don't think it exactly answers your question but it looks like our overall requirements are the same based on your code example. Hope it helps

Comment: great. can you please add this as an answer and ill accept it. So that the next guy has easier time fixing it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally execute the XPM filters per environment by defining your own custom filter which implement a FilterChain with the chain.doFilter() command executed conditionally based on your environment configuration.

You're essentially replacing the XPM filters in the web.xml with your own custom ones that conditionally execute a FilterChain.

Here's a blog explaining how to achieve that https://www.contentbloom.com/blog/conditional-sdl-experience-manager-xpm-filters-per-environment/